# Windows Server 2019 - Keep RDP connection even if user has signed out

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, windows-server-2019

So, I have this Dell server running Windows Server 2019 with RDP.

I added 2 users (A and B)

I am able to connect remotely to the server through RDP with both or any of user's credentials (everything works as expected)

**The problem:**

a) When a user connects to it through RDP, he is logged in automatically on Windows

b) When a user signs out, the RDP connection is ended.

***How it should behave:***

I need the user **NOT** to login automatically on Windows Server as the RDP connection is stablished

and

I need the RDP connection kept alive, I mean, when any user signs out, the RDP connection must be kept alive and the user (at the local computer) sees the Windows login screen (waiting for user's credentials (user and password)).

I know it is possible to reach such behavior (I have seen it on a company's network).

So, in opposit of lots of questions in this forum, I need my Windows Server prompts the login screen when a user connects to it through RDP and NOT login automatically and NOT disconnect RDP when users sign out.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You could use something else beside RDP, such as VNC that establishes the connection to the computer and mirrors everything to your computer.  There are several flavors of VNC, each with its own strengths and weaknesses.

This would allow who ever to access the computer like they have sat down at its keyboard and monitor.